# Split comma separated string in xquery?

Tags: split, xquery

I have a div element I want to split in xquery
My start

```
<tags>{for $tag in //div[@id='tags']
return 
   <tag>{$tag}</tag>}</tags>
```

The target is converting this

```
<div id="tags">Tagged: tag1, TAG2, tag3</div>
```

The expected result is

```
<tags><tag>tag1</tag><tag>TAG2</tag><tag>tag3</tag></tags>
```

Comment: what are you running this xquery expression in? In TSQL I'm getting the correct result...the only difference is no line breaks and double quotes in `for $tag in //div[@id="tags"]`

Comment: still getting `<tags><tag><div id="tags">Tagged: tag1, TAG2, tag3</div></tag></tags>`. What are you expecting?

Comment: I am expecting `<tags><tag>tag1</tag><tag>TAG2</tag><tag>tag3</tag></tags>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Supposedly](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp#string) you can use the `tokenize(string, pattern)` function to split strings based on a pattern. SQL Server 2008 doesn't have the function, but this could be your answer If whatever you're using does. I imagine it would look like this if I could get it to work:

```
 <tags>{
   for $tag in tokenize(
                 substring-after(
                   (//div[@id='tags'])[1],
                   'Tagged:'
                 ),
                 ','
               )
   return 
     <tag>{
       normalize-space($tag)
    }</tag>
}</tags>
```